# How convert n-dimensional neuron value to one-dimensional in output layer by MATLAB

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have a neural network with 1 input layer + 2 hidden layers and 1 output layer. The size of the input values are 4-dimensional.

So, the size of the hidden layer is `4` and the output layer is `1`. I mean, each neuron in hidden layer has `[1 4]` value such as `[0.1 0.2 0.4 0.5]`. When i multiply this value to weight between hidden layers and output layer and pass from `purelin` transfer function, the output hidden neuron gets a `[1 4]` value. How can i change it to one-dimensional value? Because i want to have a one-dimensional output not 4-dimensional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to check the size of `net.LW{1}`. Probably the purelin transfer function calculated the dot product of your hidden layer and the weight vector if both are [1 4] of size. Then you need to transpose your weight vector.

Actually you can always calculate the linear combination yourself with `[0.1 0.2 0.4 0.5]*net.LW{1}'`